# how to validate reactor context value in Groovy test in spring rest call

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spring-webflux, react-context, spring-test

please help on how to get reactor context value in Groovy test

```
private Mono<PersonDetail> getMemberDetailsWithName(String studNumber, PersonDetail detail) {
        Set<StudError> errors = new HashSet<>();
        return coreCustomerIndividualNameClient.getStudName(studNumber)
                .map(nameResponse -> {
                    detail.setName(mapper.map(nameResponse));
                    return detail; })
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    errors.addAll(e);
                    return Mono.just(detail);
                })
                .handle((studDetail, sink) -> {
                    StudContext studAggCtx = sink.currentContext().get(StudContext.CONTEXT_KEY);
                    studAggCtx.getErrors().addAll(errors);
                    sink.next(studDetail);
                });
    }
```

I am mocking,

```
.getStudName(studNumber) return Error.
```

I need to check whether the context got added with Error, how we can validate this in  `StepVerifier.create`

the context created in the below way through `reactor.util.context`

```
.subscriberContext(Context.of(StudContext.CONTEXT_KEY,
                            new StudContext(headers, timeoutMillis, false)))
                    .collectList().block();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `expectAccessibleContext` to gain access to the [ContextExpectations](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.ContextExpectations.html) methods. You can then use these methods to assert the state of the `Context`.

**Example**

```java
        Mono<Integer> mono = Mono.just(1)
                .subscriberContext(Context.of("key", "value"));

        StepVerifier.create(mono)
                .expectAccessibleContext()
                .contains("key", "value")
                .then()
                .expectNext(1)
                .verifyComplete();
```

[expectAccessibleContext docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.Step.html#expectAccessibleContext--)

Comment: ((StudContext) reactorContext.get(StudContext.CONTEXT_KEY)).getErrors().getAt(0).code == 1, i can aseert this way. after  StepVerifier.create.

Comment: feel free to assert in whatever way suits you best